# How do I join two arrays of struct?

Tags: c++

So this is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
typedef struct {
    float during;
    double high_fre;
    double mid_fre;
    double low_fre;
    double extra_fre;
} notes;
int main() {

    const notes song[5] =
    {   1,1,1,1,1,
        1,1,1,1,1,
        1,1,1,1,1,
        1,1,1,1,1,
        1,1,1,1,1

    };
    const notes end[6] = {
        500,118.87,0,0,0,           //indicator 
        500,118.87,158.67,0,0,
        500,118.87,158.67,188.70,0,
        1750,118.87,158.67,188.70,237.74,
        100,1902.14,1902.14,1902.14,1902.14,
        3000,0,0,0,0
    };
    const notes newsong[sizeof(song)+sizeof(end)] = song + end;

};
```

The last line obviously doesn't work. I just put it there to show what I want to do.
That is I want to create a new const notes, or better yet if I can append "end" to "song"

FYI, const notes is supposed to be interpreted as 5 columns, the first representing duration of each note, the other 4 representing 4 instruments' notes.

I'm trying to write a small programme to add an ending sequence to each piece of music to indicate that piece has ended.

Desired outcome:

```
const notes song[]=
{    1,1,1,1,1,
     1,1,1,1,1,
     1,1,1,1,1,
     1,1,1,1,1,
     1,1,1,1,1,
     500,118.87,0,0,0,           //indicator 
     500,118.87,158.67,0,0,
     500,118.87,158.67,188.70,0,
     1750,118.87,158.67,188.70,237.74,
     100,1902.14,1902.14,1902.14,1902.14,
     3000,0,0,0,0
}
```

Comment: I didn't. I simply don't know what to write. and I thought writing that would help explaining what I'm trying to do

Comment: Okay can you update the question with like what the contents of final newSongs would look like I mean song has 5 columns but end has 6

Comment: I suggest you use `std::vector` instead of C-style arrays.

Comment: @BeshambherChaukhwan Where do you see 6 columns? It has 6 rows.

Comment: @BowmanC. I'm with Barmar on this. STL: `std::vector` data structure and `std::copy` algorithm!

Comment: @rturrado or `vector::insert`

Comment: My bad it was decimal dot not comma  how about running a loop and then adding them like array.push

Comment: @Barmar So is there no way I can achieve this in it's current form? This is kind of the bases of a larger piece of code to drive the 4 instruments. The songs arrays are already generated, so I can't change it to vector now without reworking that part of the code as well. It's typically a couple thousand lines of notes each song. I could manually add the ending sequence each time I swap out a song, but I thought this way(if possible) is neater.

Comment: @BowmanC. There are two possibilities: either you reserve the correct memory amount for the song + your ending at the time the song is created so that you can later copy it into this reserved space (using memcpy or std::copy), or if it's not possible, you are much better off using vectors if you don't want to dive into C-style memory management -- otherwise you will run into memory issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C-style arrays can't be assigned or concatenated, and can't be used as the initializer for another array. You can use `memcpy()` to copy them if the element structure is POD, as in your code. But the destination array can't be `const` in this case.

Also, `sizeof` returns the number of bytes in an object, not the number of array elements. To get the number of elements, divide by the element size.

```
notes newsong[(sizeof song / sizeof *song) + (sizeof end / sizeof *end)];
memcpy(newsong, song, sizeof song);
memcpy(&(newsong[sizeof song / sizeof *song]), end, sizeof end);
```

Comment: Only use this if you are really limited to C. In C++ we use vectors. Even if you have to call a library function with a C-style array, you can pass in `vec.data()`. Also, OP's latest comment mentions that the real songs are bigger. They are most likely not created on the stack, and their size is most likely not known at compile time.

Comment: He says he can't change to vectors.

Comment: "...without touching some more code". He will have to do that anyway.

Comment: @FelixDombek He's trying to initialize a `const` array from other `const` arrays, so I think `sizeof` should work.

Comment: Those larger songs with thousands of notes are probably `malloc`ed. For that size, they should be. And you can't get the `sizeof` for that. Even if they aren't, this is so large that they should not be copied into other, even bigger, stack objects. A stack is 1 MB or so, one note is 40 bytes ... that means 25000 notes can be stored, at most. Several songs with a couple thousand each, and then copying them all? I'll bet OP runs into a stack overflow.

Comment: True, although that can be solved relatively easily by making them global instead of local.

Comment: @FelixDombek By this point, What I'm actually doing is converting midi files to the format mentioned above, then storing these in each individual txt files, which are then copied into a MCU programme to drive several electronic components. I thought I could add the end sequence in the MCU code, but like you said, I ran into memory problems. So I ended up moving this code to the txt generator, which so far is running smoothly. Thank you both for your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
struct notes {
    float during;
    double high_fre;
    double mid_fre;
    double low_fre;
    double extra_fre;
};

std::vector<notes> operator+(const std::vector<notes>& a, const std::vector<notes>& o) {
    auto copy = a;
    copy.insert(copy.end(), o.begin(), o.end());
    return copy;
}

int main() {

    const std::vector<notes> song=
    {   {1,1,1,1,1},
        {1,1,1,1,1},
        {1,1,1,1,1},
        {1,1,1,1,1},
        {1,1,1,1,1}
    };
    const std::vector<notes> end = {
        {500,118.87,0,0,0},           //indicator 
        {500,118.87,158.67,0,0},
        {500,118.87,158.67,188.70,0},
        {1750,118.87,158.67,188.70,237.74},
        {100,1902.14,1902.14,1902.14,1902.14},
        {3000,0,0,0,0}
    };

    const std::vector<notes> newsong = song + end;

    return 0;
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/zbYdvn

Comment: One wouldn't really overload the operator for that ... It would be great if you could, as an alternative, include a line how it's usually written, with insert instead of +.